# What is a good reference on the trichotomy theorem?

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory

I would like to work through the proof of Drozd's trichotomy theorem, i.e., that every finite dimensional algebra over an algebraically closed field has a representation type that is either finite, tame, or wild.

I've got Drozd's original paper and the Kliener and Roiter paper on differential graded categories that Drozd's paper is based on, but I can't find "Some evidence for an extension of the Brauer-Thrall conjecture" by Freislich and Donovan which contains the technical definition of tame/wild (and frustratingly, Drozd doesn't repeat it), so I'm not even completely sure of the technical statement that Drozd is proving.

But even the papers I do have are fairly hard to read.  They're typewritten with hand drawn formula and are a bit more informal then modern day papers tend to be.  It would be great if there were a modern exposition of this theorem that I could work through instead of using the original papers.

So does anyone have a modern reference for the proof of the trichotomy theorem?  And failing that, anyone know where I can find that Freislich and Donovan paper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might this be what you're looking for?

*Crawley-Boevey, W. W.*, [**On tame algebras and bocses**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/plms/s3-56.3.451), Proc. Lond. Math. Soc., III. Ser. 56, No. 3, 451-483 (1988). [ZBL0661.16026](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0661.16026).

Comment: Yep.  I knew about that paper but had only read the first paragraph of the intro, if I had read the rest of the intro I'd have seen it has exactly what I want.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The book "Differential Tensor Algebras and their Module Categories " by Bautista , Salmerón and Zuazua gives a modern textbook introduction (it even has solutions to the exercises !)